# reject and resolve in Promise execute at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I create a function that is responsible for logging in. it looks like: **(authService code)**

```
 login(username: string, password: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.checkUser(username, password).subscribe((output) => {
      if (output.token) {
        console.log('Log in true');
        resolve();
      } else {
       reject();
      }
    });
  });
 }
 private checkUser(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post<any>('api/auth', {username, password});
 }
```

I wanted to use Promise with resolve and reject to handle success and failure event in the call 'login' function, but I don't know why never in "if" dosn't go to the "else" section. **AND**  I do not know why onSubmitSucces and onSubmitFailure execute in same time...

**(loginComponent code)**

```
 onSubmit() {

    this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
      .then(this.onSubmitSuccess(), this.onSubmitFailure());

  }

  private onSubmitSuccess(): any {
    console.log('Success');
  }

  private onSubmitFailure(): any {
    console.log('Failure');

  }
```

Comment: You are executing `onSubmitSuccess` (and `onSubmitFailure`) immediately instead of *passing* those functions as the `then` arguments: remove the `()`. As to the first problem, you should debug and see the actual value of `output.token` so you can understand why it never goes to the `else` section. Without knowing its value we cannot say much about it than that it apparently is never a falsy value.

Comment: What's the value of output.token? Try to console.log it to see. Your code never reaches `else` because output.token is not falsey, that's it.

Comment: `this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
      .then(this.onSubmitSuccess, this.onSubmitFailure);` Hmm, so should it look like this??

Comment: See @trincot's comment above, it's the same problem as the linked question, just with `then` instead of the `setTimeout` used there.